# How can I stop assets from being imported every time I make a change in VSCode on Mac?

Tags: unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Each time I alter something in the script, save and go into Unity it freezes for a second and imports all the assets. When I am using Visual Studio Mac I don't have a similar problem. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Try Edit -> Preferences and uncheck the auto refresh:

[image]

After that you need to refresh manually with ctrl + R each time you make a change for the project to compile and try the changes you make in the project before you click play.
That allows you to change whatever you want with no refreshing and then when you want to check your changes you do ctrl + R, wait for it to compile and run. It makes sense in big projects where compilation times are big.